# Each row that contains element, then remove class in that row

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, this, each

So, I have a table and I'm trying to remove the class 'qty-holder' if a dt contains "Quantity".  I've tried several different variations of this code and cannot get it to work.

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    if ( $('dt:contains("Quantity")').length > 0 ) {
        $(this).closest('.qty-holder').css('display','none');
    }
})
```

Here's a link to the fiddle I'm working on: https://jsfiddle.net/04khega6/

In theory 'this' would be selecting the tr and searching for the closest class .qty-holder right?  Why doesn't this work?

Comment: The are no `dt` elements with that class in your code, only `div`, are you trying to remove the class from the `div` elements further down in the code?

Comment: Your question says you want to remove the class but your code is trying to hide the element. Which are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to hide it.  Sorry for the mistype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Take a look at this selector:

```
$('dt:contains("Quantity")')
```

Note that there is no reference to `this`. The selector above will find any `dt` that contains `"Quantity"` *on the entire page*, regardless of which `<tr>` it belongs to. Assuming you'd like to make it respective to the current `<tr>`, you'd want to use `$(this).find()`.

```
//Select all <dt> that contain quantity *in the current <tr>*
$(this).find('dt:contains("Quantity")')
```

---

**2.** `closest()` traverses *up* the DOM tree. If you're looking for a child (or deeper) element, you'd use `.find()`. Additionally, `.hide()` is identical to `.css("display", "none");`

```
$(this).find('.qty-holder').hide();
```

Though you said you're trying to "remove the class", so perhaps you want:

```
$(this).find('.qty-holder').removeClass("qty-holder");
```

---

**All in all, it looks like this:**

<sup>(I've declared `$(this)` as variable `$this`, by the way.)</sup>

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.find('dt:contains("Quantity")').length > 0) {
        $this.find('.qty-holder').hide();
    }
})
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04khega6/1/)

---

All that said, **you don't need the `each` loop at all**. A slightly more in-depth selector could perform this quite easily. However as I was typing this up, [Adeneo posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45175885/2026606) that  acknowledges this.

Comment: He said remove the class not hide it. Edit: you updated your code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should be able to do it with just

```
$('tr:has(dt:contains("Quantity")) .qty-holder').css('display','none');
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/04khega6/3/)

Comment: He said he wants to remove the class not hide it.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins -yet still he's using `.css('display','none')` in his own code. If he wants to use `removeClass` I'm sure he can figure it out, the issue was the selector.

Comment: Agreed. But the question in the title and repeated in the body is to remove the class.

Answer (score 1):

`closest()` only looks up the ancestor tree but the element you are looking for is not an ancestor of the row it is a descendent...so you want to use `find()`

Presumably you only want to do this if the row instance has such a `<dt>` so use `find()` for that also

```
$('tr').each(function() {
  var $row = $(this);
  if ($row.find('dt:contains("Quantity")').length) {   
    $row.find('.qty-holder').removeClass('qty-holder');
  }
});
```

Or using `:has` selector

```
$('tr:has(dt:contains("Quantity")) .qty-holder').removeClass('qty-holder');
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/04khega6/4/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a reference to the row you can use `find(querySelector)` to find element in that tree.

If you are trying to hide the element use `hide`.

Your questions asks how to remove the class, so you can use `removeClass(className)` to remove the class:

```
$('tr').each(function(){
if ( $(this).find('dt:contains("Quantity")').length > 0 ) {
    $(this).find('.qty-holder').removeClass('qty-holder');
}
```

Here's a working example:

```js
function removeQty() 
{
  $('tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('dt:contains("Quantity")').length > 0) {
       $(this).find('.qty-holder').removeClass('qty-holder');
     }
  })
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    removeQty();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="shopping-cart-table" class="data-table cart-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="first last">
      <th rowspan="1">&nbsp;</th>
      <th rowspan="1">&nbsp;</th>
      <th rowspan="1"><span class="nobr">Product Name</span></th>
      <th colspan="1"><span class="nobr">Unit Price</span></th>
      <th rowspan="1">Qty</th>
      <th class="last" colspan="1">Subtotal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="first last">
      <td colspan="50" class="a-right last">
        <button type="button" title="Continue Shopping" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('http://www.printnow123.com/')"><span><span>Continue Shopping</span></span></button>
        <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" title="Update Shopping Cart" class="button btn-update"><span><span>Update Shopping Cart</span></span></button>
        <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="empty_cart" title="Clear Shopping Cart" class="button btn-empty" id="empty_cart_button"><span><span>Clear Shopping Cart</span></span></button>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="update_cart_action_container" />
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        //<![CDATA[
                                        Event.observe(window, 'load', function()
                                        {
                                            // Internet Explorer (lt 8) does not support value attribute in button elements
                                            $emptyCartButton = $('empty_cart_button');
                                            $cartActionContainer = $('update_cart_action_container');
                                            if ($emptyCartButton && $cartActionContainer) {
                                                Event.observe($emptyCartButton, 'click', function()
                                                {
                                                    $emptyCartButton.setAttribute('name', 'update_cart_action_temp');
                                                    $cartActionContainer.setAttribute('name', 'update_cart_action');
                                                    $cartActionContainer.setValue('empty_cart');
                                                });
                                            }

                                        });
                                    //]]>
                                    </script>
                                    <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="first odd">
      <td class="action-td">
        <a href="http://www.printnow123.com/checkout/cart/delete/id/7/form_key/Y2jY96Qm2Wwtdmx5/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5wcmludG5vdzEyMy5jb20vY2hlY2tvdXQvY2FydC8,/" title="Remove item" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="pr-img-td">
        <a href="http://www.printnow123.com/test-2.html" title="Test 2" class="product-image"><img src="http://www.printnow123.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/80x80/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/x/f/xframebannerstand.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="Test 2"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="product-name-td">
        <h2 class="product-name">
          <a href="http://www.printnow123.com/test-2.html">Test 2</a>
        </h2>
        <dl class="item-options">
          <dt>Paper Type Test</dt>
          <dd>Standard </dd>
          <dt>Quantity</dt>
          <dd>30</dd>
        </dl>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="cart-price">
<span class="price">$0.50</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="qty-holder">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table_qty_dec">-</a><input name="cart[7][qty]" value="30" size="4" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table_qty_inc">+</a>
          <a class="edit-qty" href="http://www.printnow123.com/checkout/cart/configure/id/7/" title="Edit item parameters"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="td-total last">
        <span class="cart-price">
<span class="price">$15.00</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="action-td">
        <a href="http://www.printnow123.com/checkout/cart/delete/id/9/form_key/Y2jY96Qm2Wwtdmx5/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5wcmludG5vdzEyMy5jb20vY2hlY2tvdXQvY2FydC8,/" title="Remove item" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="pr-img-td">
        <a href="http://www.printnow123.com/test-2.html" title="Test 2" class="product-image"><img src="http://www.printnow123.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/80x80/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/x/f/xframebannerstand.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="Test 2"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="product-name-td">
        <h2 class="product-name">
          <a href="http://www.printnow123.com/test-2.html">Test 2</a>
        </h2>
        <dl class="item-options">
          <dt>Paper Type Test</dt>
          <dd>Glossy </dd>
          <dt>Quantity</dt>
          <dd>30 </dd>
        </dl>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="cart-price">
<span class="price">$0.50</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="qty-holder">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table_qty_dec">-</a><input name="cart[9][qty]" value="30" size="4" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table_qty_inc">+</a>
          <a class="edit-qty" href="http://www.printnow123.com/checkout/cart/configure/id/9/" title="Edit item parameters"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="td-total last">
        <span class="cart-price">
<span class="price">$15.00</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="last odd">
      <td class="action-td">
        <a href="http://www.printnow123.com/checkout/cart/delete/id/11/form_key/Y2jY96Qm2Wwtdmx5/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5wcmludG5vdzEyMy5jb20vY2hlY2tvdXQvY2FydC8,/" title="Remove item" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="pr-img-td">
        <a href="http://www.printnow123.com/test-business-card.html" title="Test Business Card" class="product-image"><img src="http://www.printnow123.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/80x80/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/i/simple-b-card.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="Test Business Card"></a>
      </td>
      <td class="product-name-td">
        <h2 class="product-name">
          <a href="http://www.printnow123.com/test-business-card.html">Test Business Card</a>
        </h2>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="cart-price">
<span class="price">$0.05</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="qty-holder">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table_qty_dec">-</a><input name="cart[11][qty]" value="500" size="4" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="table_qty_inc">+</a>
          <a class="edit-qty" href="http://www.printnow123.com/checkout/cart/configure/id/11/" title="Edit item parameters"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="td-total last">
        <span class="cart-price">
<span class="price">$25.00</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: don't know what I was thinking. Thought it was being fired by a button click. totally forgot about the `tr` `each`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `closest` with `find`:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
  if ($('dt:contains("Quantity")').length > 0) {
    $(this).find('.qty-holder').css('display', 'none');
  }
})
```

Comment: He said remove the class not hide it.